# Print all prime numbers up to a certain number

Tags: java

So I'm trying to print the prime numbers leading up to the number the user inputs. The only problem is it's now not printing the numbers. I don't see anything wrong with the code and when I checked with my teacher he said it should work.

```
static void primeNumbers(int n) {
    System.out.println("All the prime numbers up to " + n + " are -->");

    for (int count = 2; count == n; count++){
      boolean isPrime = true;
      for (int prime = 2; prime < n; prime = prime++) {
        if (n % prime == 0) {
          isPrime = false;
        }
        if(isPrime){
          System.out.println(n);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @david That just caused it to print the user's number infinitely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using the following:

```
public static void primeNumbers(int n) {
  System.out.println("All the prime numbers up to " + n + " are -->");

  for (int count = 2; count <= n; count++) {
    int factors = 0;
    for (int prime = 1; prime <= count; prime++) {
      if (count % prime == 0) {
        factors++;
      }
    }
    if (factors == 2) {
      System.out.println(count);
    }
  }
}
```

In your previous code, if `n` was 2, it would run once, and then stop. If `n` was not 2, it would never run.

Also, `prime=prime++` is equal to `prime++`

But your logic is broken, since in the original program, you never stored how many factors the number had. We have the variable `factors` to help store that for us. If the number has two factors (e.g, `factors==2`), then we know it is prime.

When `n` is 10, it prints:

```
All the prime numbers up to 10 are -->
2
3
5
7
```

Comment: I used this code and now the user's number just prints indefinitely. I don't know why it's happening because it sounds like it works fine.

Comment: It should be `count % prime` i think and not `n % prime`

Comment: @TylerP I've fixed it.